# Let $A$ be open, show that $\text{Int}(\partial A)= \emptyset$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

My proof is definitely wrong, because I fail to use one of the hypothesis of $A$ being open, and manage to conclude without it, but that would mean I could use this proof for any set. So I wonder, where is my mistake?

Suppose $A$ is open. $\text{Int}(\partial A) = \emptyset \iff \forall x \in \partial A, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists y \in B(x, \epsilon) \text{  such that } y \not \in \partial A$.
Suppose that for a fixed and for a fixed  $\epsilon$, $B(x,\epsilon) \subset \partial A$, then $\partial A$ would be an empty set as there would always exist an open ball for a fixed element of $\partial A$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

To see where your mistake is, consider the case $A = \Bbb Q \cap [0, 1]$. In this case the interior of the boundary of $A$ is the entire interval. So what statement in your proof doesn't apply to this $A$?

Comment: I suppose it would be this part: $B(x,\epsilon) \subset \partial A$

Answer (score 1):

If there was a point  $p $ in the interior of the boundary,  that point would be contained in an open set  $U _p$ with  $U_p\subset \partial A $...  Now  $\partial A=\bar A \cap \bar {A^c} $.  And $A^c $ is closed.   Thus $\bar {A^c}=A^c $.Therefore  $U_p\subset A^c $, contradicting $p\in\partial A $...